# How to hide tabs and make them appear after a specific optionbutton is selected?

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, commandbutton

I posted earlier, but since have made some good progress and figured some stuff out by myself!

I have nearly finished my project, but need to make the last real bit of code, then just some general tidying up.

**What I want to do**

- I currently have two page in a MultiPage userform - one called 'main' and one called 'extra
- I want Main to always be shown to the user
- I want Extra to be hidden and for this page to be shown automatically under a specific condition

I have a question on my userform (using Option Buttons):

"Did the customer ask about an extra product today?"

***If the answer to this question is no***

When the user hits the command button (after filling out the rest of the form), do nothing special - just return all the values to the worksheet.

***If the answer is yes***

When the user hits the command button, I want them to be taken to the 'extra' page. They will fill out some additional check-boxes, then hit another command box, which will return the info from both the 'main' and 'extra' sheets together, into the same row of the worksheet.

In brief: 
I want my 'extra' tab to be hidden, only to appear when 'yes' is selected, and for the results all to go back to the worksheet. If you want to see my workbook:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2F...it?usp=sharing

Can this be done? Thank you for your help :D

**How I have hidden my Pages**

- I have changed the properties of the multipage to : "Style: fmTabStyleNone."

Now I just need the code to make my command button send the user to the next page, if required.

This isn't working for me. Any ideas??

```
If ProductEnquiryYes.Value = True Then
    With MultiPage1
        If .SelectedItem.Index < .Pages.Count - 1 Then
            .Value = .SelectedItem.Index + 1
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the propriety Visible.
**If the Tabs name is **TabStrip1**:**

```
TabStrip1.Tabs(1).Visible = False
```

hide the second Tab. The Index Start From 0 to n-1 tabs.
When you Show, you can also active the tabs with:

```
TabStrip1.Tabs(1).Visible = True
TabStrip1.Value = 1
```

**With Multipages:**

```
MultiPage1.Pages(1).Visible = True
MultiPage1.Value = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I appreciate it. I have made a mistake, I have multipage set up, not tabs. I tried using what you suggest, changing TabStrip1 to MultiPage1 and Tabs to Pages, but it didn't work. Sorry, I will edit my original question